# Appending string to the variable

Tags: bash

I read some file line by looking for some specific string. When I find I assign it to the var.
But when I try to append to that string I have problem. Instead of add to the end of var i get var where characters at the beginning are replaced by new characters.

Example:

```
echo $fileToGet
newVar=$fileToGet".xml"
echo $newVar
```

Output:

```
c024z160205
.xmlz160205
```

And what I want is: `c024z160205.xml`
I think I tried everything what is on Stack, several ways of appending but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `\r` at the end of var. Before assigning line to var `fileToGet` I do something like:

`newVar=$(echo "$fileToGet" | tr -d '\r')`

and after concatenation I have what I want.

I edit this answer because it contains false informations. What really was the problem @chepner described in comment: `'The terminal simply displays any characters following the carriage return at the beginning of the line, overwriting the earlier characters.'`
Thanks!

Comment: The assignment didn't replace any characters; the terminal simply displays any characters following the carriage return at the beginning of the line, overwriting the earlier characters. You can see that `newVar` contains all the expected data with something like `echo "$newvar" | hexdump`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working for me, try using:

```
newVar="${fileToGet}.xml"
```

Instead of `newVar=$fileToGet".xml"`; you gotta put the variable also inside the quotes.

Tell me if it works now.

Comment: I tried it also before but I didn't work, anyway I found solution - look at my answer.

Comment: Yeah, i saw it, but it's strange.. unless fileToGet has some 'special' chars in it, it should be appended at the beginning, what are the values of fileToGet?

Comment: It was `c024z160205`.

Comment: Well, if it worked trimming the \r, i assume it's enough :)

Comment: Quotes are not needed here; the parameter expansion in an assignment statement is not subject to word splitting or pathname expansion, which would be the two reasons to quote it.